# What is the best way to dynamically change the innerHTML of a Stencil component?

Tags: stenciljs

I have this component:

```
<ifx-accordion-item initialcollapse="true" caption="Label" id="myaccordionitem">
      Content for Initial Item. 
</ifx-accordion-item>
```

Now, I want, as a user of this component, to change its innerHTML content dynamically.

If I grab it, and then do `myaccordionitem.innerHTML = "new content"`, neither `componentWillUpdate()` nor  `@Listen('slotchange')  onSlotChange() { .. }` get invoked, and on top of that, the new content is not inserted correctly inside the slot, but outside the slot, outside the shadow DOM, so I am guessing this is not a correctly way of doing it.

The only other way I can think of is via a Prop, but in this case, that's not an option. So what do I do?

Comment: Please show the full component code; you are now kinda saying: _My car doesn't drive, what is wrong?_

Comment: Already found a solution. I used onSlotChange as an event handler on the slot itself.